# SQL help needed - Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

have a query that I would appreciate some help on, I'm not too sure why its not working.

```sql
Select 
  ContactID
, CASE 
     WHEN Special_credit = '0' AND Credit_Check_Status__c = 'Approve' THEN 'SENT' 
     ELSE NULL 
  END as Sent_1
, CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) as Sent_1_date
, Sent_RFS
, Sent_RFS_date
, Sent_Welcome
, Sent_Welcome_date
, Serial_number
, Active
, Credit_Check_Status__c 
from Submitted_Applications_Master 
where 
Sent_1_date > '1/01/1900' 
AND Sent_1_date is not null 
AND Sent_1 = 'SENT'
```

IF SOMEONE COULD TELL ME THE PROBLEM AS TO WHY THE 'Sent_1' & 'Sent_1_date' are not being populated even though there is records that seem to meet the criteria.

If more info is needed to understand this question please let me know.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the full query?

Comment: Select
ContactID,
CASE WHEN Special_credit = '0' AND Credit_Check_Status__c = 'Approve' THEN 'SENT'
ELSE NULL
END as Sent_1,
CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) as Sent_1_date,
Sent_RFS, 
Sent_RFS_date,
Sent_Welcome,
Sent_Welcome_date,
Serial_number,
Active,
Credit_Check_Status__c
from Submitted_Applications_Master
where Sent_1_date > '1/01/1900'
AND Sent_1_date is not null
AND Sent_1 = 'SENT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to aliases in the where-clause directly.  You'll have to repeat the criteria:

```sql
Select 
  ContactID
, CASE 
     WHEN Special_credit = '0' AND Credit_Check_Status__c = 'Approve' THEN 'SENT' 
  END as Sent_1
, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) as Sent_1_date
, Sent_RFS
, Sent_RFS_date
, Sent_Welcome
, Sent_Welcome_date
, Serial_number
, Active
, Credit_Check_Status__c 
from Submitted_Applications_Master 
where 
CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) is not null 
AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) > '1900-01-01' 
AND 
  CASE 
     WHEN Special_credit = '0' AND Credit_Check_Status__c = 'Approve' THEN 'SENT' 
  END = 'SENT'
```

...or use an outer query:

```sql
select
  x.ContactID
, x.Sent_1
, x.Sent_1_date
, x.Sent_RFS
, x.Sent_RFS_date
, x.Sent_Welcome
, x.Sent_Welcome_date
, x.Serial_number
, x.Active
, x.Credit_Check_Status__c
from (

  Select 
    ContactID
  , CASE 
       WHEN Special_credit = '0' AND Credit_Check_Status__c = 'Approve' THEN 'SENT' 
    END as Sent_1
  , CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) as Sent_1_date
  , Sent_RFS
  , Sent_RFS_date
  , Sent_Welcome
  , Sent_Welcome_date
  , Serial_number
  , Active
  , Credit_Check_Status__c 
  from Submitted_Applications_Master

) x
where 
x.sent_1_date is not null 
AND x.sent_1_date > '1900-01-01' 
AND x.Sent_1 = 'SENT'
```

Also, no need to check for null in your CASE statement.  If you don't provide an ELSE, that's what gets returned by default.

Last thing -- `01/01/1900` is an ambiguous date format, it'd be better to use an ISO date -- `1900-01-01`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Adam, ill try out the outer query